# Permission denied to access a file in python

Tags: python, file-io, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I am using pytesseract's image_to_string method and the PIL library to read the text of a simple image, but i am getting a PermissionError saying "Access is Denied". This is the line causing the error `print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image=Image.open("screenshot.png")))`

I tried rearranging the lines of code, running VsCode as admin, switching to a different directory, running it via Cmd Prompt as admin but none seemed to work

Comment: Do you get the same error using `open()`?

Comment: It says: TypeError: Unsupported image object when i try to use `open()`

Comment: Rather than show a line of code that calls 3 functions, try splitting it up into 3 lines with one function call per line so we know which part is causing the error. Then show us the value, and type of the things you are passing to that function and the result. Try adding some debug statements like `print(os.getcwd())` so you can see what directory you program is running in.

Comment: I get Access Denied when another application opened the file in exclusive mode, maybe your image viewer is holding it open. Another possibility is that the file is not being closed by the Python interpreter itself, from a previous run. On the other hand, `Image.open`  opens the file for reading, which should be allowed in any case. Try to make a copy of the file and open that copy. Also open it in a viewer, to make sure it is not corrupted or truncated to zero bytes.

Comment: Is your `open()` call pointintg to `io.open()`? It should not try to interpret the file, just open it for reading and maybe give you a better message.